# SQL stored procedure failing in large database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a particular SQL file in which i copy all contents from on table in a database to another table in another database.

The traditional INSERT statements are used to perform the same operation. However this table has 8.5 Million records and it fails. The queries succeed with a smaller database.

Also in when i run the select * query for that particular table the SQL query express shows out of memory exception.
In particular there is one table that has some many records. So this table alone i want to copy from the old Db to the new Db.

What are alternate ways to achieve this?

Is there any quick work around by which we can avoid this exception and make the queries succeed?

Let me put it this way. Why would this operation fail when there are a lot of records?

Comment: "...  and it fails" - fails how? Do you get any error messages? "SQL query express shows out of memory" - that's just management studio trying, and failing, to display all of the results on the results pane. I seem to remember it copes a lot better if you switch to "Results as Text" rather than "Results as grid". (Not that trying to view and make sense of 8.5 million rows as a single result set will usually make sense anyway)

Comment: It does not show any error message. It just fails to complete and exits the SQL file. The out of memory exception comes in SQL query express and not in management studio.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter which tool the exception is coming from - it's almost certainly an issue with it trying to *display* all of the results in that tool, and not a server issue as such.

Comment: My main concern is the SQL queries failing and not the tool not being able to show the records. I just added that to stress that this is a huge DB.

Comment: Using bcp seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this counts as "traditional INSERT", but have you tried "INSERT INTO"?

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp